# references for theory of viscosity solutions

Tags: reference-request, differential-equations

I am looking for some references to learn about viscosity solutions. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is "Optimal Control and Viscosity Solutions of Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman Equations" by Bardi, Martino, and Capuzzo-Dolcetta, Italo.